# Does anyone know how to get function call stack (backtrace) programatically in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know  how to get function call stack (backtrace) programatically in javascript?

is this even possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this page has an answer for you: http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/

Comment: i also had found it just after posting this but left the question open anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This wasn't available at the time the question was asked but now all modern web browsers support `console.trace()`. Be aware that this feature is considered as non-standard. More about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.trace